# Can a damaged neoprene (polychloropren) or rubber coating be cured (hardened) using a hot air gun and a curing agent?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Polymers can be hardened by a process known as vulcanization (curing of elastomers), a chemical process that involves a curing agent and heat.

According to Wikipedia, for the vulcanization of rubber, sulfur is used, whilst for neoprene (polychloroprene) metal oxides are used (MgO, ZnO and somtimes Pb3O4).

I wonder if a polymer coating (assumed neoprene) that was altered by cleaning alcohol (isopropanol) and became tacky/sticky, can be hardened again by applying a suitable hardening agent and heating with a simple temperature controlled hot air station.
If yes, which the temperature ranges and which precautions?

Envisaged application: [restoring the coating of a laptop palmrest that became tacky/sticky](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/158724/chemical-product-to-restore-a-rubberized-coating-that-became-tacky-sticky).

Comment: Haha, yes, hypothetically. I recommend you split this in three questions: what is that polymer on laptop palmrests and similar applications that turns sticky? What happened to the same when it turned sticky? And lastly how can I harden it again?

Comment: Just buy a new palmrest...